# Using a regex as a template with Python

Tags: python, regex, templates

I have the idea to use a regex pattern as a template and wonder if there is a convenient way to do so in Python (3 or newer).

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("/something/(?P<id>.*)")
pattern.populate(id=1) # that is what I'm looking for
```

should result in

```
/something/1
```

Comment: That's not really what a regex is for. SilentGhost's example is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is not what regexes were made for, but I could use a regex for matching and as a template in my case.

Comment: It is useful for building urls like Django does in `{% url %}` tag.

Comment: This would be very useful. It would be great if you could generate URLs (i.e., string formatting) with the same code that you use to route URLs (i.e., regular expressions).

Comment: I just put something like this together... see below.

Comment: One more note: if you are using this for URLs and happen to be using this on Django's framework, take a look at the `reverse` function, which generates URLs based on your url router: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the regex is just a bunch of named groups joined by some predefined string, you can convert the regex it into a [template string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) like this

```py
from string import Template
def pattern2template(regex, join_string):
    tmpl_str = join_string.join(["$"+x for x in regex.groupindex.keys()])
    # prepend string to match your case
    tmpl_str = join_string + tmpl_str
    return Template(tmpl_str)
```

In you case this gives:

```
>>> x = pattern2template(pattern, "/something/")
>>> print(x.template)
/something/$id
>>> print(x.substitute(id="myid"))
/something/myid
```

Answer (score 5):

Below is a a light-weight class I created that does what you're looking for. You can write a single regular expression, and use that expression for **both** matching strings and generating strings.

There is a small example on the bottom of the code on how to use it.

Generally, you construct a regular expression normally, and use the `match` and `search` functions as normal. The `format` function is used much like `string.format` to generate a new string.

```
import re
regex_type = type(re.compile(""))

# This is not perfect. It breaks if there is a parenthesis in the regex.
re_term = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)\(\?P\<(?P<name>[\w_\d]+)\>(?P<regex>[^\)]*)\)")

class BadFormatException(Exception):
    pass

class RegexTemplate(object):
    def __init__(self, r, *args, **kwargs):
        self.r = re.compile(r, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<RegexTemplate '%s'>"%self.r.pattern
    
    def match(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''The regex match function'''
        return self.r.match(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def search(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''The regex match function'''
        return self.r.search(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def format(self, **kwargs):
        '''Format this regular expression in a similar way as string.format.
        Only supports true keyword replacement, not group replacement.'''
        pattern = self.r.pattern
        def replace(m):
            name = m.group('name')
            reg = m.group('regex')
            val = kwargs[name]
            if not re.match(reg, val):
                raise BadFormatException("Template variable '%s' has a value "
                    "of %s, does not match regex %s."%(name, val, reg))
            return val
        
        # The regex sub function does most of the work
        value = re_term.sub(replace, pattern)
        
        # Now we have un-escape the special characters. 
        return re.sub(r"\\([.\(\)\[\]])", r"\1", value)

def compile(*args, **kwargs):
    return RegexTemplate(*args, **kwargs)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Construct a typical URL routing regular expression
    r = RegexTemplate(r"http://example\.com/(?P<year>\d\d\d\d)/(?P<title>\w+)")
    print(r)
    
    # This should match
    print(r.match("http://example.com/2015/article"))
    # Generate the same URL using url formatting.
    print(r.format(year = "2015", title = "article"))
    
    # This should not match
    print(r.match("http://example.com/abcd/article"))
    # This will raise an exception because year is not formatted properly
    try:
        print(r.format(year = "15", title = "article"))
    except BadFormatException as e:
        print(e)
```

There are some limitations:

- The format function only works with keyword arguments (you can't use the `\1` style formatting as in `string.format`).
- There is also a bug with matching elements with sub-elements, e.g., `RegexTemplate(r'(?P<foo>biz(baz)?)')`. This could be corrected with a bit of work.
- If your regular expression contains character classes outside of a named group, (e.g., `[a-z123]`) we will not know how to format those.

Answer (score 3):

that's not what regex are for, you could just use normal string formatting.

```
>>> '/something/{id}'.format(id=1)
'/something/1'
```

Answer (score 2):

For very simple cases, probably the easiest way to do this is by replacing the named capture groups with format fields.

Here is a basic validator/formatter:

```py
import re
from functools import partial

unescape = partial(re.compile(r'\\(.)').sub, r'\1')
namedgroup = partial(re.compile(r'\(\?P<(\w+)>.*?\)').sub, r'{\1}')


class Mould:
    def __init__(self, pattern):
        self.pattern = re.compile(pattern)
        self.template = unescape(namedgroup(pattern))

    def format(self, **values):
        try:
            return self.template.format(**values)
        except KeyError as e:
            raise TypeError(f'Missing argument: {e}') from None

    def search(self, string):
        try:
            return self.pattern.search(string).groupdict()
        except AttributeError:
            raise ValueError(string) from None
```

So, for example, to instantiate a validator/formatter for phone numbers in the form `(XXX) YYY-ZZZZ`:

```
template = r'\((?P<area>\d{3})\)\ (?P<prefix>\d{3})\-(?P<line>\d{4})'
phonenum = Mould(template)
```

And then:

```
>>> phonenum.search('(333) 444-5678')
{'area': '333', 'prefix': '444', 'line': '5678'}

>>> phonenum.format(area=111, prefix=555, line=444)
(111) 555-444
```

---

But this is a very basic skeleton that overlooks many regex features (like lookarounds or non-capturing groups, for example). If they are needed, things can get quite messy pretty quickly. In this case, the other way around: generating the pattern from the template, although more verbose, may be more flexible and less error-prone.

Here is the basic validator/formatter (`.search()` and `.format()` are the same):

```py
import string
import re

FMT = string.Formatter()


class Mould:
    def __init__(self, template, **kwargs):
        self.template = template
        self.pattern = self.make_pattern(template, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def make_pattern(template, **kwargs):
        pattern = ''
        # for each field in the template, add to the pattern
        for text, field, *_ in FMT.parse(template):
            # the escaped preceding text
            pattern += re.escape(text)
            if field:
                # a named regex capture group
                pattern += f'(?P<{field}>{kwargs[field]})'
            # XXX: if there's text after the last field,
            #   the parser will iterate one more time,
            #   hence the 'if field'
        return re.compile(pattern)
```

Instantiation:

```py
template = '({area}) {prefix}-{line}'
content  = dict(area=r'\d{3}', prefix=r'\d{3}', line=r'\d{4}')
phonenum = Mould(template, **content)
```

Execution:

```py
>>> phonenum.search('(333) 444-5678')
{'area': '333', 'prefix': '444', 'line': '5678'}

>>> phonenum.format(area=111, prefix=555, line=444)
(111) 555-444
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the compile until after the substitution:

```
pattern = re.compile("/something/(?P<%s>.*)" % 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling potential names for a package that does this, I found [xeger](https://github.com/crdoconnor/xeger):

```py
>>> from xeger import Xeger
>>> x = Xeger(limit=10)  # default limit = 10
>>> x.xeger("/json/([0-9]+)")
u'/json/15062213'
```

It is specifically designed to generate random values (rather than using input values) for the capture groups found in a pattern, but there should be enough overlap in the purpose that bits of the implementation could be reused.

(As a side note, I've always thought that there should be a subset of the regular expression grammar that supports this templating use without caveat or hacks. Could be an interesting project.)